# Javascript: Modify an object from a pointer

Tags: javascript, pointers, object

I'm making a digital library with three classes: Library, Shelf & Book. Shelves have their contents as an array of books. Books have two methods, enshelf and unshelf. When a book gets unshelfed it's supposed to set delete the instance of itself from the shelf it's on and then set it's location property to null. How can I modify the shelf it's sitting on? In the constructor if I change this.location, it will just give that property a new value instead of modifying the variable it points to. I feel like this is really simple and I'm overlooking something super basic.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

//books
var oldMan = new Book("Old Man and the Sea", "Ernest Hemingway", 0684801221);
var grapes = new Book("The Grapes of Wrath", "John Steinbeck", 0241952476);
var diamondAge = new Book("The Diamond Age", "Neal Stephenson", 0324249248);

//shelves
var shelf0 = new Shelf(0);
var shelf1 = new Shelf(1);

//libraries
var myLibrary = new Library([shelf0, shelf1], "123 Fake Street");

//these need to accept an unlimited amount of each
function Library(shelves, address) {
    this.shelves = shelves; //shelves is an array
    this.address = address;
    this.getAllBooks = function() {
        console.log("Here are all the books in the library: ");
        for (var i = 0; i < this.shelves.length; i++) {
            console.log("Shelf number " + i + ": ");
            for (var j = 0; j < this.shelves[i].contents.length; j++) {
                console.log(this.shelves[i].contents[j].name);
            }
        }
    }
}

function Shelf(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.contents = [];
}

function Book(name, author, isbn) {
    this.name = name;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.location = null;
    this.enshelf = function(newLocation) {
        this.location = newLocation;
        newLocation.contents.push(this);
    }
    this.unshelf = function() {
        _.without(this.location, this.name); //this doesn't work
        this.location = null;
    }
}


console.log("Welcome to Digital Library 0.1!");

oldMan.enshelf(shelf1);
myLibrary.getAllBooks();
oldMan.unshelf();
myLibrary.getAllBooks();
```

Comment: use [].splice() to modify, functional solutions like _.without() make copies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small issue with your `unshelf` method, easily remedied:

```
this.unshelf = function() {
    this.location.contents = 
        _.without(this.location.contents, this);
    this.location = null;
}
```

Consider, however, that `shelf` and `unshelf` should be methods of `Shelf`, and not of `Book`.  Also, if you must have this method, surround it with a guard, like so:

```
this.unshelf = function() {
    if (this.location) {
      this.location.contents = 
          _.without(this.location.contents, this);
      this.location = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of small issues:

`without` works on arrays and returns a copy of the array with the elements removed - the original is untouched. So you need to pass `location.contents` instead of just `location` *and* reassign it back to `location.contents`.

Also you add the whole book to the Shelf, then try to remove it by name, so it doesn't match and get removed. So just pass `this` to `without`:

```
this.unshelf = function() {
    if (this.location) {
        this.location.contents = _.without(this.location.contents, this);
        this.location = null;
    }
}
```